# How to retrieve data in spinner from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for how to retrieve an edit text from another activity in my spinner but I can't find how there are only tutorials how to retrieve data from the same activity and store it in a spinner.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "another activity". Do you mean you need to reference a spinner that exists in one class from a different class?

Comment: I want to recover an EditText which comes from the first activity for exemple  each time I add a name in the first activity it is stored in the spinner of the second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user adds the name in the first activity, store it in a bundle and pass it the second activity. Then populate the spinner dynamically from an array in the second activity from the intent extra passed from the first activity, when the second activity is created. Spinner is populated both from array in your .xml file or dynamically, I described above that fits your needs in this case.

```
Intent sendNameIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
sendNameIntent.putStringExtra("name",String.ValueOf(nameEdittext.getText()));
startActivity(sendNameIntent);
```

Then in your Second Activity you do something like this.

```
String nameExtra = getIntent().StringExtra("name");
ArrayList<String> spinnerData = new ArrayList<>();
spinnerData.add(nameExtra);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData);

yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

This will populate your spinner with the name passed from the first activity. This should accomplish what you are looking for. Please let me know if something is missing.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you illustrate what you say with a simple code if you want

Comment: I have updated my answer by adding sample code to give you an idea. Good luck.

Comment: Then you need to pass two different string extras by giving them unique names, like "personOne", "personTwo"..etc instead of "name". Then retrieve them in the second activity the same way I did. Or you can persist in SharedPreferences then retrieve them and populate your spinner. It can be done multiple ways depending what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks a lot of context, so I am assuming you are using a spinner to select a property, persist it, and retrieve it in another activity.

You could, for example, simply store the index of an item into a shared preference, and retrieve it in another activity, or maybe pass it in a `Bundle`.

There are so many ways of passing data between activities or fragments in Android...

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am not looking for how to select a property, keep it and recover it in another activity but the opposite I want to recover an edit text which comes from another activity and store it in a spinner each time I add a name in the firs tactivity it is stored in the spinner of the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few trick to approach what you need to:
 - if you are using MVVM architecture, make it as one activity with 2 or more fragment. In first fragment save the value of your edittext to the viewmodel and retrieve the value from viewmodel in the second fragment.
 - If you need to use activities, save your value list to sharedpreference and retrieve them from the other activity.